# SetInterval in Javascript

Tags: javascript

i have this for example of code..

```
 function rotate() {
      rx = 50 * Math.cos( angle ) + 200;
      ry = 50 * Math.sin( angle ) + 200;
      for( var i = 0; i < plots; i++ ) {
        x = 100 * Math.cos( angle ) + rx;
        y = 100 * Math.sin( angle ) + ry;
        turnangle = Math.atan2( y - ry, x - rx ) * 180 / Math.PI + 90 + 'deg';
        plotcache[ i ].rotate( turnangle );
        plotcache[ i ].position( x, y );
        angle += increase;
      }
      angle += 0.06;
    }

setInterval( rotate, 1000/30 );
```

What does `setInterval( rotate, 1000/30 )` it should `setInterval( rotate, 1000 )..`??

Answer (score 6):

It calls `rotate` at approximately 30 times per second. This is a reasonably common frame rate; I'm guessing this is an animation.

Comment: because it using Math constant??

Comment: No, nothing of the sort. Because `setInterval`'s second arguments is a millisecond value, and 1000 is the number of milliseconds in a second.

Comment: Basically it's self-documenting code. Writing `setInterval(x,1000/30)` is the same as writing `setInterval(x,33)` except that it's easier to read/modify the frame rate (it's 30). Doing it the other way by pre-calculating on paper and writing `33` means you then have to do mental calculations to figure out the frame rate.